# How to remove all gridlines and ticks all lines in lines chart in javascript taken from cdn)

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

Guys I have js chart line and I want to remove all `gridlines` and `ticks` both from `xAxes`  and `yAxes`.

I tried:

```
 options: {legend: {display: false},scales : {  xAxes : [ {gridLines : {display : false}}, ] ,
 yAxes:[ {gridLines: {display :false}}]},

}
```

But it only removes **gridlines**. I tried to add to **xAxes** `ticks{display : false}` but it does not work. Any idea how to remove all **gridlines** and **ticks** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
        display: false,
        drawBorder: false
      },
      ticks: {
        display: false
      }
    }],
    xAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      },
      ticks: {
        display: false
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

[Demo.](https://jsbin.com/jedirezayi/1)